# If Jews shouldn't marry non-Jews, why did prominent Jewish leaders do so in the bible?

Tags: historical-figures, intermarriage

Moses's wife was a Midianite. 
Solomon had many non-Jewish wives.
Abraham married Hagar, who was an Egyptian.

If Jews shouldn't marry non-Jews, how were these prominent Jewish leaders able to do so?

Comment: You wrote "do so", but only mentioned people in the past predating Ezra's takana.

Comment: These are all as yet unsourced facts that I recall: Before the giving of the Torah, there were no jews and non-jews, (So Moses was no more or less of a jew than tsipora). Solomon's wives converted, though many did so without forsaking their idolatrous tendencies. David married a non jewess while at war per the laws in the verses in deuteronomy. She had children and then converted, along with them.

Comment: The classifications of women in the question are nationalities. "Jew" is not. There is a false dichotomy.

Comment: @WAF What do you mean it's not a nationality?

Comment: How did David marry non jewess again? By force marriage? So by force is okay but wooing is not?

Comment: English is not my main language. In Indonesian there are no tenses. That's why I wrote "do so". Sorry. Intermarriage rate for jews are like 50% though now but that's irrelevant for these questions because it's the people rather than the leaders who do so. Let's face it. Not like real jews are "pure blood" either. Otherwise, jews from Ethiopian would look exactly the same with jews from German, which look exactly the same with ancient jews.

Comment: Sanhedrin 107a about david's wife, Yeb. 76a-b about solomon and pharaoh's daughter. possibly Exodus ch 19 and 24 for national conversion?

Comment: Can you turn that into an answer.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Are you trying to prove my point about Ezra, or making some other comment?  וכן מפורש על ידי עזרא ואשר לא נתן בנותינו לעמי הארץ ואת בנותיהם לא נקח לבנינו:

Comment: @avi הרי אלו לוקין מן התורה

Comment: what is your point????? 7 nations from the torah, everyone else from Ezra

Comment: @ShmuelBrinישראל שבעל עכו"ם משאר האומות דרך אישות. או ישראלית שנבעלה לעכו"ם דרך אישות הרי אלו לוקין מן התורה שנאמר לא תתחתן בם בתך לא תתן לבנו ובתו לא תקח לבנך. אחד שבעה עממין ואחד כל אומות באיסור זה. וכן מפורש על ידי עזרא ואשר לא נתן בנותינו לעמי הארץ ואת בנותיהם לא נקח לבנינו:

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Why do you choose to ignore the explicit words of the Rambam as if they don't exist?  And why do you choose to ignore the explicit words of Tanach?

Comment: @avi how do you explain ישראל שבעל עכו"ם משאר האומות דרך אישות. או ישראלית שנבעלה לעכו"ם דרך אישות הרי אלו לוקין מן התורה שנאמר לא תתחתן בם בתך לא תתן לבנו ובתו לא תקח לבנך. אחד שבעה עממין ואחד כל אומות באיסור זה. The Rambam is *explicit* that it's biblical (not a decree from Ezra)

Comment: because I'm not a Tzedoki :)

Comment: Because it is now a biblical decree.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Rambam also lists Kiddush and Havdalah as Biblical commandments, min ha torah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What exactly is your problem? Rambam states clearly that its a Torah command since Ezra. Just as kiddish and havdalah were only established later.

Comment: It's a good thing Ezra wasn't a prophet. And it wasn't instituted by Ezra, it was expanded in understanding.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin it is a biblical commandment to not drive a car on shabbat even though nobody made that ruling until the 20th century.

Comment: Driving a car means lighthing a fire. While it is controversial I can sort of understand. Not marrying chinese or ethiopian or british is not the same law. It's indeed addition.

Comment: The fact that this question had, before my vote, a score of -2, suggests that there is something wrong here. It is a GREAT question.

Comment: In one hand, I've heard that no more mitzvah after torah. On the other hand, after Ezra, tada, no more intermarriage. Then now, 50% of jews outside israel intermarry. I mean you don't think nothing is to explain? Doesn't see anything strange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Torah commands the Jewish people not to marry the daughters of the 7 Cananite nations in Israel.

Devarim 7:1-4

> א  כִּי יְבִיאֲךָ, יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ, אֶל-הָאָרֶץ, אֲשֶׁר-אַתָּה
>   בָא-שָׁמָּה לְרִשְׁתָּהּ; וְנָשַׁל גּוֹיִם-רַבִּים מִפָּנֶיךָ הַחִתִּי
>   וְהַגִּרְגָּשִׁי וְהָאֱמֹרִי וְהַכְּנַעֲנִי וְהַפְּרִזִּי, וְהַחִוִּי
>   וְהַיְבוּסִי--שִׁבְעָה גוֹיִם, רַבִּים וַעֲצוּמִים מִמֶּךָּ.  1 When
>   the LORD thy God shall bring thee into the land whither thou goest to
>   possess it, and shall cast out many nations before thee, the Hittite,
>   and the Girgashite, and the Amorite, and the Canaanite, and the
>   Perizzite, and the Hivite, and the Jebusite, seven nations greater and
>   mightier than thou; ב  וּנְתָנָם יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ,
>   לְפָנֶיךָ--וְהִכִּיתָם:  הַחֲרֵם תַּחֲרִים אֹתָם, לֹא-תִכְרֹת לָהֶם
>   בְּרִית וְלֹא תְחָנֵּם.   2 and when the LORD thy God shall deliver them
>   up before thee, and thou shalt smite them; then thou shalt utterly
>   destroy them; thou shalt make no covenant with them, nor show mercy
>   unto them; ג  וְלֹא תִתְחַתֵּן, בָּם:  בִּתְּךָ לֹא-תִתֵּן לִבְנוֹ,
>   וּבִתּוֹ לֹא-תִקַּח לִבְנֶךָ. 3 neither shalt thou make marriages with
>   them: thy daughter thou shalt not give unto his son, nor his daughter
>   shalt thou take unto thy son. ד  כִּי-יָסִיר אֶת-בִּנְךָ מֵאַחֲרַי,
>   וְעָבְדוּ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים; וְחָרָה אַף-יְהוָה בָּכֶם, וְהִשְׁמִידְךָ
>   מַהֵר.    4 For he will turn away thy son from following Me, that they
>   may serve other gods; so will the anger of the LORD be kindled against
>   you, and He will destroy thee quickly.

After the First Exile, Ezra explained this verse to mean the daughters or sons of any non-Jewish nation.

In [Chapter 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a09.htm) of Ezra, Ezra complains that the Jewish people have married all sorts of foreign women, including from the 7 nations.

In [Chapter 10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a10.htm) of Ezra, It is decided that they will repent, and make a fence and not allow any intermarriage at all.

All examples of Jewish Leaders marrying non-Jews in the way of European Kings, happened before the Decree of Ezrah.

Comment: How can Ezra change Torah commandment? I mean that means there is a drastic change of interpretation of what the commandments mean right? Can you be more specific and give reference. Where in the Torah does it say you must not marry the daughters of the 7 Cananite women. What Ezra actually said and what's his reasoning?

Comment: It's not a drastic change. It's a fence.

Comment: Isn't that like adding rules? Or is Torah allow some "flexibility" in interpretation?

Comment: The Torah always allows a fence which is defined and recognized as a fence. As for flexibility in interpretation, that exists whether it is allowed or not. We are human, and the Torah was given to humans, not angels.

Comment: the 7 nations were already long gone by then. This was after Sancheiriv.

Comment: So you can't add or deduct things from Torah but you can change interpretation and hence for all practical purpose have different rules

Comment: So Ezra admit "hand of the princes and rulers hath been first in this faithlessness". Yet, it's not faithlessness because it was okay before Ezra. Hmm.... Oh they also took from the 7 nations. But now, which jews are truly pure blood anyway?

Comment: The princes amd leaders refers to his generation, not previous ones. Its poetic language. Blood is not the issue, avoiding non Jewish practices is.

Comment: But jewish practices have changed all the time. No body is doing the old jewish practices anymore. Oh but most doable practice are done. I see. Fair enough.

Comment: @JimThio You don't seem to understand the difference between adding to/subtracting from the Torah and making fences and Rabbinic laws. As long as those fences are understood to not be *from the Torah*, they still remain binding on Jews in a way similar to how laws from the Torah are binding.

Comment: Oh I see. Those are not mitzvah. Those are fences outside mitzvah. So in a sense, some "authority figure" can add rules. A king may extend sabbath to include friday and sunday and anyone breathing there will be stoned to death (on monday), for example. I mean, won't happen. But technically they can.

Comment: That example would not work. And the king does not have the authority to do that, only the high court.

Comment: @JimThio: Rabbis can expound verses to mean different things and the Torah law will change accordingly. Also, the Rabbis can make their own fences and this is not Biblical. The verse simply is referring to the 7 nations only. One can interpret it to include all idolatrous nations, or any non-Jewish nation (e.g., a Ger Toshav). It could be that the Rabbis disputed what these verses are referring to, and Ezra held it included all non-Jewish women. Although, the simple understanding is that all agree that this is the Torah tradition as the Book of Ezra should not be adding anything to the Torah.